# Heroku - dump and load single table to shared postgres database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I wonder if there is an easy way to dump or load the content of just one table to heroku shared database (postgres).
There is pgbackups addon reccomended by heroku but according to docs it supports dumping and loading the whole database.

What I need is to just dump/load single table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Taps (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps) to pull data down from your PG database. Using Taps, you can do specific table(s), like such:

```
heroku db:pull --tables users
```

You can do more than one table as well where the table names are comma delimited, like:

```
heroku db:pull --tables users,posts
```

**Edit:** As some comments have pointed out, taps has been deprecated and replaced.

New mechanism is through `pg:pull` and `pg:push` which can be seen by their new docs (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull).

No longer supporting individual tables, you can pull the db to your local by the following example:

```
heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi
```

or updating the remote from your local:

```
heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app sushi
```

Comment: Thanks, could you also explain what I can use as 'PG database' in this case? It can be any PG database accessible from internet or my local computer?

Comment: You have the pg gem i assume already from your question.  So if you're using pg locally too, which I highly recommend, taps pulls the data from your heroku pg db to your local. Hope this helps

Comment: The link in this answer now redirects to a page with no information about using taps.

Comment: `db:pull` and `db:push` were deprecated a long time ago. They are replaced with `pg:pull` & `pg:push`, but those commands can not export/import specific tables, only the whole database.