# Rails 3 & heroku - cloning table between databases

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I have local machine that does a load of data processing before pushing the resulting data up to heroku using db:push and taps - this is clunky, but pretty fast. The problem is that taps is pretty flaky and is nolonger supported with toolbelt.

One option is to run the results up to production as they are generated - on the fly - by using a connection string and something like:

`ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:production)`

- but there are 1000000s of records and individually inserting the records this way takes **way** too long.

Is there a way I could use something like raw sql:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;
```

but where the new table is on different db connection? ....

Or is there a better method for cloning a local table and pushing up to heroku?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dump the table from your local and pipe the file into your remote, similar to what  I outline here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151503/95741

Comment: not sure... is that something you want? I don't know that pg_dump carries over the keys, checkout the man page `man pg_dump`

Comment: i'll check it out - thanks a lot. with a bit of thinking, i think i get around the indexes problem - thanks for the suggestion.