# table missing from heroku pg_restore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, psql

I have a rails app deployed on heroku with postgres db.

My goal is to get a copy of the db to my local machine. So, I followed the 3-liner instruction: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#export

There were errors in my localhost app, and I traced the problem to be that **`pg_restore` didnt fill one of the tables, while rest of the table is filled**

Question is:

1. how is this possible?
2. what are the things I can check to debug how this happened?

EDIT:

looks like this is behaving nicely (and solves my problem):
`rake db:drop db:create` then `pg_restore db.dump`

but this is not: `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` then `pg_restore db.dump`

Answer (score 1):

In order to check if it's a heroku bug or not try to backup/restore using `psql`:

```
pg_dump -o -h host -U user -d database -n "\"SCHEMA\"" > test.dump
psql -U user database < test.dump
```

If you have all tables presented it means it's better to log a case with heroku support.

Comment: Worth trying. You can get heroku db credentials here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778365/postgres-on-heroku-and-dumping-single-table-to-dump-file