# Restore a table using pg:backups restore

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Reading Heroku postgres documentation just came across this:

> Unlike with the previous pgbackups commands, you cannot restore a partial backup into an existing database. When you run pg:backups restore, all data is deleted from the target database before restoring the backup.

[source 1](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#restoring-backups)
[source 2](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/623)

is there a way to restore a single table using `pg:backups restore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778365/postgres-on-heroku-and-dumping-single-table-to-dump-file) a try at your own risk.

Important: Take a backup of your database before trying this.